# Should it be bachelor programme, bachelor's programme, bachelor program... or what?

Tags: punctuation, idiomatic-language, terminology, genitive-construction

Which of the following is/are correct:

1 a bachelor's programme

2 a bachelor's program

3 a bachelorprogram

4 a bachelor programme

5 a bachelor program

Personally I'd go with (1) or possibly (4), but that's just my own intuition; I can't say for sure what's actually considered correct. I'd be immensely grateful if someone could help me out here :)

Edit: I'd also be very grateful if the person who downvoted my question would let me know in a comment what's wrong with it, and if there's any way I can improve it. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/program-programme/ Some contextxt in which you use it would be helpful.  .

Comment: @GWarner Ah, so the spelling of program(me) is just a question of BrE vs AmE! Huh, I didn't know that... Thank you! The context in which it'd be used would be a university context, I suppose, as in e.g. "He's enrolled in a bachelor's programme in arts" or "They offer a bachelor's programme in education"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In formal correspondence you should endeavor to spell it the 'native way'. BrE for Brits and presumably Australian, AmE for American.

We know as intellectual adults what the word is, but seeing a foreign spelling of a word can cause unnecessary pause, like colour/color does for many Americans.

Understand the difference here: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/program-programme/

As far as punctuation it is bachelor's not bachelors because it is possessive not plural.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! One more question though: is it ok to omit the genitive altogether – that is, is: would 4 and 5 be correct as well? And what about writing it as one rather than two words?

Comment: bachelorprogram isn't a word in itself, unless you are referring to a foreign language's penchant for creating a word from English words in order to identify something that does not translate well into their own language (I found it used on a Norwegian website), but then that would be in Norwegian, mixing languages in this manner is hardly proper for formal correspondence.

Comment: https://wmich.edu/writing/rules/degrees This source cites a good guideline for the different uses of bachelor-bachelors-bachelor's.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, G Warner! I really appreciate your help!